# Non-trivial centers, abelian towers, Lang

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently reading a proof in Lang's algebra that says that: because $G$ is a finite $p$-group, with non-trivial center "we have an abelian tower for $G/Z$ by induction, we can lift this abelian tower to $G$ to show that $G$ is solvable." I'm a little confused about this. If anyone could fill me in on the details that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then the center $Z(G)$ is non-trivial. This can be proven immediately by partitioning $G$ to conjugacy classes.

Now one proves by induction that every finite $p$-group is solvable. The initial cases are trivial. Assume now the claim holds for groups of order $p^k$ whenever $k<n$, and let $G$ be of order $p^n$. The center is not trivial, as stated above. If $Z(G)=G$, then $G$ is abelian thus solvable. Otherwise, the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ is solvable by hypothesis, and $Z(G)$ is trivially solvable, hence so is $G$.

Answer (score 2):

He means that as $|Z|>1, |G/Z|<|G|$, so his induction hypothesis will work on group $G/Z$. Since you have not mentioned the hypothesis here, but as Ii know the hypothesis is all groups with order strictly less than $|G|$ are solvable, so it applies on $G/Z$ and thus $G/Z$ has an solvable series(abelian tower) say,

$e<H_1/Z<H_2/Z,<....H_k/Z=G/Z$,

Now lifting this tower means

$e<H_1/Z\times Z<H_2/Z\times Z,<....H_k/Z\times Z=G/Z\times Z\cong G$